# What Hogwarts classes are taught to two houses at once?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I remember from my *mumble* about nine *mumble* rereads of the Harry Potter series that the following classes Harry took were taught to more than one house in the same lesson:

- Potions with the Slytherins
- Herbology with the Hufflepuffs
- Care of Magical Creatures with the Slytherins
- broomstick riding with at least the Slytherins (maybe other houses, too?)

I don't remember any student from a house that isn't Gryffindor being mentioned in the sections on Transfiguration, Charms, Defense Against Dark Arts, History of Magic, or Divination. That would mean McGonagall had to teach twice as many classes as Snape, if both subjects got the same number of lessons (which I think I recall).

Were any subjects other than Potions, Herbology, and Care of Magical Creatures taught to more than one house in the same lesson? And do we know why some subjects are taught to more students at the same time than others?

Comment: I've always assumed that *all* classes included all houses.

Comment: @Joe L. I think at one point in PoA, Harry mentions only seeing Ernie and Justin at Herbology, and not at Potions, so at least it's not all four houses at all classes. And more than 40 students also seems a bit much for one class. And there's a lot of looking at timetables and saying "we have double Potions with the Slytherins" and "Herbology with the Hufflepuffs" without mentioning the other two houses.

Comment: I don't think it's a school policy not to mix houses in the same class, but just through scheduling and student's preferences to take classes with their friends, sometimes classes are predominately only one or two houses.

Comment: @Joe L. No, all students have to take the core classes (Potions, Herbology, Transfiguration, Charms, DADA, History of Magic) for the first five years. There is no choice at all until third year. And Harry has all his classes with his whole Gryffindor year for the first two years until they choose whether to take Divination / Muggle Studies / Ancient Runes / etc

Comment: This happens in real life. To fill a class, you schedule students taking the class. If that means pulling from two houses, then do it. Also, remember, Harry has no reason to notice or care about classes he _doesn’t_ take, where, say, Snape teaches potions to a class of Hufflepuffs and Ravenclaws.

Comment: Why not all of them? When I was in high school in the UK, all classes were completely mixed. There were two bands per year, and each band contained five forms, with each form containing roughly 35 pupils. Every lesson contained students from all forms in a band (divided up by ability), and there was the odd occasion where bands were mixed too. Form was just like Harry Potter's "houses" - where you went for register, and who all your points went to.

Comment: the pure number of students. there aren't many students taking divination, i presume, so they don't have to share houses, whereas transfiguration, which most students take, would need two houses because there are more students.

Answer (score 16):

Another example:

- **Gryffindors and Hufflepuffs share Muggle Studies classes**

  Ernie Macmillan [tells Harry and Ron in PoA chapter 12](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/hogwarts/classes/muggle-studies-class.html) that Hermione had never missed a Muggle Studies class, implying that he was taking the class together with her.

Muggle Studies is one of the optional classes, with fewer students taking it. It's plausible that *all* Houses are mixed in such classes (well, assuming any Slytherins take Muggle Studies!)

In post-OWL years, when there are fewer students taking *any* subject, more (all?) classes are mixed; for instance:

- **Gryffindor, Slytherin, and Hufflepuff (probably Ravenclaw too) share 6th-year Potions classes**

  There were a total of 12 students who achieved either Outstanding or Exceeds Expectations on their Potions OWL and were able to advance to NEWT class. In HBP, the first Potions class includes Harry, Ron, Malfoy, and Ernie Macmillan; it's mentioned that Ernie is the only Hufflepuff there, which suggests all four Houses were represented.
- **Gryffindor and Slytherin share 6th-year DADA classes**

  Malfoy is there to snigger at Snape's bullying of Harry and Ron during their DADA classes in HBP; we also learn that Crabbe and Goyle would have been there but failed their DADA OWLs.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few instances, of varying canon status:

- **Gryffindors and Ravenclaws might share Transfiguration classes.**

  Quoting Luna in *Half-Blood Prince* (her OWL year):

  > “Oh, it's been alright. A bit lonely without the D.A. Ginny’s been nice, though. She stopped two boys in **our Transfiguration class** calling me ’Loony’ the other day —”

  That sounds as if they’re in the same class.

Comment: The Patil twins are both Gryffindor in the films though, aren't they?

Comment: @randal'thor you're right, ffs. *hits movies with a stick*

Comment: Yes, bloody films [grumbles] :-) Still, that means the second half of your answer doesn't work. Maybe you should edit it out?

Answer (score 2):

In PoA, the book lists all of the Gryffindor students' boggarts except Harry and Hermione, who are said to be the only students who did not face the boggart in the class.  No one from any other house is mentioned, so this heavily implies that, in 3rd year at the very least, each class takes DADA separately.

Answer (score 1):

Gryffindors share Potions with Slytherins and Herbology with Hufflepuffs and Charms with the Ravenclaws. Divinaton/Muggle studies/Arithmancy/Care of magical creatures have students from all houses. If a student chose to study the subject, they're in the class. In 6th and 7th year classes have students from all classes as they're NEWT level and have less students in them.