# Did Harry ever have classes with Ravenclaws?

Tags: harry-potter

Listening to the books with audible and I realized the Gryffindors never had classes with Ravenclaws. The only Ravenclaw in Harry's year mentioned seems to be Padma Patil. The Gryffindors seems to have a lot of classes with Hufflepuff (Ernie and Hannah often mentioned) and obviously Slytherin.

But how come they never have class with Ravenclaws? Did Ravenclaws even have more than 1 student for Harry's year?

Comment: Related: [What Hogwarts classes are taught to two houses at once?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105879/31394)

Comment: The dupe is wider since it addresses the question of house interaction *in general* (otherwise we could end up with "*Did Harry ever have classes with Slytherins*", "*Did Harry ever have classes with Hufflepuffs?*" and "*Did Harry ever have classes with Ravenclaws?*" (not to mention "*Do we ever see Ravenclaws having classes with Hufflepuffs?*", etc etc)

Answer (score 6):

**Apparently Gryffindors and Ravenclaws share Transfiguration classes.**

Because Luna and Ginny were in the same class, at least in their OWL year (and possibly before that too, given that they seem to know each other fairly well by *HP and the Order of the Phoenix*):

> "Oh, it's been alright. A bit lonely without the D.A. Ginny’s been nice, though. She stopped two boys in our Transfiguration class calling me 'Loony' the other day —"
>
> <sub>-- Luna, *HP and the Half-Blood Prince*</sub>

<sup>Hat-tip to [alexwlchan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105881/31394) for making me aware of this.</sup>

**But we never see *Harry* sharing classes with Ravenclaws, at least not 'on-stage'.**

There are many scenes where he's in class with Malfoy, Crabbe, and Goyle (Slytherin), and some where he's with Ernie Macmillan or Justin Finch-Fletchley (Hufflepuff), but never with any Ravenclaws.

In fact, it's possible he never shared classes with them, given that he doesn't seem to know any of them very well. The main Ravenclaws we know about in his year are Padma Patil, who's only familiar to him due to her sister Parvati being in Gryffindor with him, and Terry Boot, Anthony Goldstein, and Michael Corner, who are described as follows in their first appearance:

> three Ravenclaw boys he was pretty sure were called Anthony Goldstein, Michael Corner, and Terry Boot
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

Doesn't really sound as though he's been sharing classes with them for four years.

(So in answer to your question "*Did Ravenclaws even have more than 1 student for Harry's year?*" - **yes, definitely**.)